# Referencing a new inserted column Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to reference a cell in the below formulaes.  **'AUA Summary'!$D$9** . Each time the macro runs a new column D is inserted.

**The Problem:** When the column is inserted my reference moves to  **
    `'AUA Summary'!$E$9.`   How do I get to reference `'AUA Summary'!$D$9` even if a new cell is inserted using VBA.  My formuleas are below.

```
=IF(ROUND((SUM('BLL UTADS'!$D:$D)-'AUA Summary'!$D$9)+
(SUM('BLL UTADS'!$E:$E)-'AUA Summary'!$D$15),2)=0,"OK",
"Balances don't tie on BLL UTADS to AUA Summary Sheet")

=IF((SUM('BLL Prestige'!$D:$D)-'AUA Summary'!$D$10)+
(SUM('BLL Prestige'!$E:$E)-'AUA Summary'!$D$16)=0,"OK",
"Balances don't tie on BLL Prestige to AUA Summary Sheet")

=IF((ROUND('AUA Detail'!$D$9+'AUA Detail'!$D$23-'AUA 
 Summary'!$D$11,1)+ROUND('AUA Detail'!$D$15+'AUA Detail'!$D$29-'AUA 
 Summary'!$D$17,1))=0,"OK","Check the Totals tie")
```

The issue is on the `'AUA Summary'` Tab the reference keeps changing. I have tried a VBA recorder , but i keep getting the same issue.

Each of these **formuleas will be in a Cell.**

Comment: What's the macro that's running?

Comment: The Macro is running and inserting new numbers in column D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Indirect()`

For example

```
'AUA Summary'!$D$9
```

can be written as

```
INDIRECT("'AUA Summary'!$D$9")
```

This way even when the columns move, it will refer to the same cell.

The other way is to use `Index`

For example `D9` in Excel 2007+ can be written as `INDEX(1:1048576,9,4)` or `INDEX(INDIRECT("1:" & ROWS(A:A)),9,4)` for any version of Excel